# Inverse of a function of two variables with respect to one variable, and the curvature with respect to the other

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, inverse, inverse-function

Consider a function of two variables $f(x,y)$, where $x\in [0,\infty)$ and $y\in [0,1]$, which is a convex combination of two functions $f_a(x)$ and $f_b(x)$. Both, $f_a(x)$ and $f_b(x)$, are  increasing and concave in variable $x$, saturate to $1$ as $x\to \infty$, and are such that $f_a(x)\leq f_b(x)$ for all $x$.  Thus, the function $f$ has the form$$ f(x,y) = y f_a(x) + (1-y) f_b(x).$$
The conditions on $f_a$ and $f_b$ imply that $f$ is also positive, concave, increasing, and saturates to $1$ asymptotically in $x$.

We are interested in the relation between $x$ and $y$ when the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, denoted by $f'_x(x,y)$ is equal to a fixed positive constant $c$ i.e., what is $x(y)$ such that $f'_x(x,y) = c$? More specifically, we are interested in knowing the curvature of $x(y)$.

An example that illustrates this:
$$
    f_a(x) = 1-Ae^{-x} \hspace{1em} f_b(x) = 1-Be^{-x}
$$
such that $A>B$. Then $f'_x(x,y) = c$ is given by --
$$
(yA+(1-y)B)e^{-x} =c
$$ From which we can solve for $x(y)$ to get --
$$
x(y) = \ln\bigg(\frac{yA+(1-y)B}{c}\bigg)
$$
This is concave in $y$. Similarly, one can think of examples where $x(y)$ is convex in $y$. However, are there functions $f_a$ and $f_b$ such that resulting $x(y)$ obtained is neither concave nor convex in $y$? How could we go about finding such functions?

Edit: After unsuccessfully trying of cook up (counter)examples, I am now pursuing the following approach:
Since we are interested in the relation between $x$ and $y$ when $f'_x(x,y) = c$, we can write
$$ y f_a'(x) + (1-y) f_b'(x) = c$$
which simplifies to give
$$ y(x) = \frac{c - f_b'(x)}{f_a'(x)-f_b'(x)}.$$
This is $y(x)$, and to learn about its curvature, we need to study its second derivative. The second derivative is a messy looking equation, but it can be seen that the sign of the second derivative will depend of the sign and magnitudes of terms like $c-f_b'(x)$, $f_a'(x)-f_b'(x)$, and the third derivatives of $f_a(x)$ and $f_b(x)$. So it seems likely that one could think of constraints such that $y''(x)$ will be positive for some values of $x$ and negative for some. But then, would the same hold $x(y)$? (we will have to worry about the existence of the inverse under those constraints, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for some time, I came up with the following example. It is not a particularly nice one, but unfortunately it is the best I've been able to find.

Take $f_b(x)=1$ for all $x$ and
$$f_a(x)=1-\frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt 7}+\frac{1}{56}\left(6\sqrt 7\arctan\left(\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt 7}\right)+14\ln(x)-7\ln\left(x^2-3x+4\right)\right).$$
Now, it is an easy computation that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f_a(x)=1.$$
The derivative of $f_a$ in $(0,\infty)$ reads
$$f_a'(x)=\frac{1}{x\left(x^2-3x+4\right)}$$
which is positive and strictly decreasing in $(0,\infty)$. Thus, $f_a$ is increasing and concave.

We choose now $c=\frac{1}{4}$ and get
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{4f'_a(x)}=\frac{x^3-3x^2+4x}{4},$$
$$y'(x)=\frac{3x^2-6x+4}{4}>0$$
and
$$y''(x)=\frac{3}{2}(x-1).$$
Thus, $y(x)$ is strictly increasing but neither convex nor concave in any open neighbourhood of $x=1$.

Finally, we can realize that the following Lemma holds:

**Lemma:** Let $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable and strictly increasing. Then:

1. The inverse $g^{-1}$ is strictly increasing in its domain.
2. If $g$ is convex in $(a,b)$, then $g^{-1}$ is concave in $(g(a),g(b))$.
3. If $g$ is concave in $(a,b)$, then $g^{-1}$ is convex in $(g(a),g(b))$.

**Proof:**

1. is obvious. For 2. and 3. we have
   $$\left(g^{-1}\right)'(x)=\frac{1}{g'\left(g^{-1}(x)\right)}$$
   and
   $$\left(g^{-1}\right)''(x)=-\underbrace{\frac{\left(g^{-1}\right)'(x)}{\left(g'\left(g^{-1}(x)\right)\right)^2}}_{>0}g''\left(g^{-1}(x)\right).$$
   Hence, the sign of $\left(g^{-1}\right)''$ is the opposite of the sign of $g''$.

Applying this Lemma to $y(x)$ we can conclude that $x(y)$ is strictly increasing but neither concave nor convex in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What was your approach to building this example? In your choice of function, $f_a(x)$ was taking negative values for some small values of $x$. The positivity of $f_a$ can be achieved by shifting the graph along the $x-$axis by some amount. After this shift, there are two things that need to be ensured -- the change of sign of $y''$ should happen for positive $x$, and that $y$ should take a value between $0$ and $1$ when that happens. For the latter, I suppose the appropriately choosing the "free parameter" $c$ will suffice.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I did the construction the other way around: $y(x)$ was supposed to be a function that is strictly increasing and neither concave nor convex. Hence, $x^3+x$. Since the concave-convex change needs to occur for positive $x$ I shifted this to $(x-1)^3+(x-1)+2=x^3-3x^2+4x$. As you noted, the value of $y$ can be adjusted by $c$. So, by choosing $f_b(x)=1$, we get $f_a'(x)=\frac{1}{x^3-3x^2+4x}$ which we can then integrate to arrive at $f_a$. The additive constant is thereby given by the condition $f_a(x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I think you forgot to write that $f_a$ is supposed to be positive. Although admittedly it can be inferred from $f$ being positive. Your shifting solution should indeed resolve this problem.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks a lot once again. I will try to use this idea to construct examples where $f_b$ isn't a constant. I don't think this should be too much of a problem, because if we take $f_b$ to be something like $f_b = 1 - 0.00001 e^{-x}$, then I would expect that the resulting $y(x)$ would inherit the features that were derived in your solution.